# SQL - Need to group data by 2 different columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I know that the question sounds like this is going to be an easy question, but let me explain.  I have a result set where I get

```
     Count    Team   Score  Team2   Score
-----------------------------------------
        10    TeamA    1    TeamB     2
        7     TeamB    2    TeamA     1
```

Now, because I have the same result, but the Teams are in different columns I get the 2 results.  I am looking for a way of retrieving the one result like so:

```
     Count    Team   Score  Team2   Score
-----------------------------------------
        17    TeamA    1    TeamB     2
```

Is this possible?

EDIT

```
SELECT TOP 5 SUM([CountryCount]) AS [CountryCount]
      ,[Country], [CustomFieldB], [CustomFieldC], [CustomFieldD]
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT([Country]) AS [CountryCount], [CustomFieldB], [CustomFieldC], [CustomFieldD]
          ,[Country]
      FROM (
        SELECT [CustomFieldA] AS [Country], [CustomFieldB], [CustomFieldC], [CustomFieldD]
          FROM [Target]
         WHERE [TargetListID] = xxx
        ) as tbl
     GROUP
        BY [Country], [CustomFieldB], [CustomFieldC], [CustomFieldD]
    ) as T
 GROUP
    BY [Country], [CustomFieldB], [CustomFieldC], [CustomFieldD]
 ORDER
    BY [CountryCount] DESC;
```

Comment: And the query that gave you that result set looks like??? And the tables you are querying look like??? Give all the details you can in your question, as people do not have Chrystal balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code accomplishes the desired results using a Common Table Expression and a `UNION ALL`. The data was made up using the query and results provided.

```
DECLARE @Target TABLE (
    [TargetListID] int,
    [CustomFieldA] varchar(5),
    [CustomFieldB] int,
    [CustomFieldC] varchar(5),
    [CustomFieldD] int
    ) 

INSERT INTO @Target
    VALUES
        (1, 'TeamA', 1, 'TeamB', 2),
        (1, 'TeamA', 1, 'TeamB', 2),
        (1, 'TeamA', 1, 'TeamB', 2),
        (1, 'TeamA', 1, 'TeamB', 2),
        (1, 'TeamA', 1, 'TeamB', 2),
        (1, 'TeamA', 1, 'TeamB', 2),
        (1, 'TeamA', 1, 'TeamB', 2),
        (1, 'TeamA', 1, 'TeamB', 2),
        (1, 'TeamA', 1, 'TeamB', 2),
        (1, 'TeamA', 1, 'TeamB', 2),
        (1, 'TeamB', 2, 'TeamA', 1),
        (1, 'TeamB', 2, 'TeamA', 1),
        (1, 'TeamB', 2, 'TeamA', 1),
        (1, 'TeamB', 2, 'TeamA', 1),
        (1, 'TeamB', 2, 'TeamA', 1),
        (1, 'TeamB', 2, 'TeamA', 1),
        (1, 'TeamB', 2, 'TeamA', 1)

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
            COUNT([CustomFieldA]) AS [Count],
            [CustomFieldA] AS [Team1],
            [CustomFieldB] AS [Team1Score],
            [CustomFieldC] AS [Team2],
            [CustomFieldD] AS [Team2Score]
        FROM (
            SELECT
                    [CustomFieldA],
                    [CustomFieldB],
                    [CustomFieldC],
                    [CustomFieldD]
                FROM @Target
                WHERE [TargetListID] = 1
            ) AS tbl
        GROUP BY
            [CustomFieldA],
            [CustomFieldB],
            [CustomFieldC],
            [CustomFieldD]
    )
SELECT
        SUM([Count]) AS [Count],
        Team1 AS Team,
        Team1Score AS Score,
        Team2 AS Team2,
        Team2Score AS Score
    FROM (
        SELECT
                CTE.[Count],
                CTE.[Team1],
                CTE.[Team1Score],
                CTE.[Team2],
                CTE.[Team2Score]
            FROM CTE
            WHERE CTE.[Team1Score] <= CTE.[Team2Score]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
                CTE.[Count],
                CTE.[Team2],
                CTE.[Team2Score],
                CTE.[Team1],
                CTE.[Team1Score]
            FROM CTE
            WHERE CTE.[Team2Score] < CTE.[Team1Score]
        ) AS U
    GROUP BY
        [Team1],
        [Team1Score],
        [Team2],
        [Team2Score]
    ORDER BY [Count] DESC
```

This query gives the desired result.

```
Count       Team  Score       Team2 Score
----------- ----- ----------- ----- -----------
17          TeamA 1           TeamB 2
```